# Copy Table from file on SD card to App database table

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created database with one table.I uploaded and downloaded that database file to and from  "SD card/Dropbox" successfully.I am storing that file upon downloading in app internal storage.Now when i am trying to copy table from that file to app database table its not inserting record.

```
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        db= new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String currentDBPath = "//data//"+ "loginscreen.example.com.girviapp" +"//databases//"+DATABASE_NAME;
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        String con=context.getDatabasePath(currentDBPath).getAbsolutePath();
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("GirviDrop", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File myInternalFile = new File(directory ,"GirviDrop.db");
        if (myInternalFile.exists())
        { 
            db.delete_allsource_table();
            db.create_allsource_table();
            db.copy_to_allsource_table(currentDB.getAbsolutePath(),myInternalFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
```

Function for Copy:

```
 public int copy_to_allsource_table(String dbpath,String backpath)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db1.openDatabase(dbpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        String attachquery="ATTACH '"+ dbpath +"' AS AAA";
        db1.execSQL(attachquery);

        SQLiteDatabase db2 = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db1.openDatabase(backpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        String attachquery2="ATTACH '"+ backpath +"' AS YYY";
        db1.execSQL(attachquery2);
        String countQuery1 ="INSERT INTO 'AAA'.'"+ TABLE_CONTACTSDUMMY +"' SELECT * FROM 'YYY'.'"+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"'";

        Cursor cursor1 = db1.rawQuery(countQuery1, null);
       // String countQuery11 =" SELECT * FROM 'YYY'.'"+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"'";
       // Cursor cursor11 = db1.rawQuery(countQuery11, null);

        return cursor1.getCount();
    }
```

Result : `No Record Inserted`

But there are records present in 'YYY.TABLE_CONTACTS' While i run the code by uncommenting the commented line its returning no. of records.

Comment: Have you opened the database file using a SQLite client such to ensure that the table is indeed there?

Comment: I did it now and resolved my problem.But Sql insert query not working